# Scroll horizontally starting from right to left with CSS overflow:scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

So I am wondering if there is a possibility to have a different starting position with the `overflow:scroll` value;

When you start scrolling in a `div` the default behaviour is to scroll from left to right:

```
|<--Scrollbar-Starting-Left-->_________________________________________________|
```

would it possible that it starts at the right?

```
|_________________________________________________<--Scrollbar-Starting-Right-->|
```

[In my example](http://jsfiddle.net/marczking/HyRTx/) the `red` and `green` items are first visible, I'd like the `green` and `blue` item to be visible first :)

I've tried `direction:rtl;` but no luck

Answer (score 44, accepted):

#### You can of course use [`direction:rtl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction)

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function(){
  document.querySelector('.box').scrollLeft = this.value;
})
```

```css
.box{
  width: 320px;
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  overflow: scroll;
  direction: rtl;  /* <-- the trick */
}

.box::before{ content:''; display:block; width:400%; height:1px; }
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>
<br>
<input placeholder='scrollLeft value'>
```

[**FiddleDemo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4d9C5/)

This may be useful using direction http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/

Comment: I somehow was applying `direction:rtl;` wrong I see now :S Super thank you

Comment: It does add all the elements inside the box, the direction: rtl, it might give unintended consequences to the direction of the text.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot more simple than I assumed it might be. Thanks! To @Trader's point - you can put a child element inside with direction set by to `ltr`

Comment: @Voodoo Precisely, but that should be in the example so it keeps everything inside in the same order.

Comment: Doesn't work in Mobile IE: it scrolls in the wrong direction :-(

Comment: This is pure genius!

Answer (score 7):

I don't Know about any solution with just CSS but you can use Jquery to change the initial position of the scrollbar like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#box').scrollLeft($(this).height())
})
```

Check this [**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HyRTx/1/)

Comment: @SajadLfc thanks but in this case you won. And I learn something new ... :D do you know if that property has any compatibility issue?

Comment: :It is compitible with all major browsers http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp

Comment: @Danko It has a wide usage in All RTL languages such as Persian, Arabic, Hebrew, ...

Answer (score 3):

I've been working in a project and for me works very well like this:

```
overflow-x: scroll;   
overflow-y: hidden;   
white-space: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 2):

With javascript you can just set [scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollLeft) property when page gets loaded (using `el.scrollLeft = el.scrollWidth - el.clientWidth;`).

Answer (score 1):

There is an unexpected behavior if you add closing parenthesis at the end of text for the top answer. (Tested in Chrome 54)

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="inner_box">
        <div class="item" style="background:red;"></div>
        <div class="item" style="background:green;"></div>
        <div class="item" style="background:blue;">te(st)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Watch this feedle for result : http://jsfiddle.net/mm37pqxa/

Comment: It is unclear what the unexpected behavior is.  Please elaborate and explain what your answer adds over and above the existing answers.  How does this answer address the OP's question?

Comment: your demonstrated fiddle has an issue even if you center your text or align it to the left. The closing bracket is cut off either way, so I don't think this is an issue with the scrolling itself, it's definitively an other issue unrelated to the scrolling. Cheers

Comment: Okay, never mind my previous answer. You are right, `direction:rtl;` does change the alignment of some characters. I think it's symbols like `?`, `!` and `.` Somehow the bracket falls into this as well. I guess this has to do with the direction text normally flows when being red in a rtl-language. Your fix to this would be to assign `direction: ltr;` to your child-element to reinstate the "normal" right-to-left flow again. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zztp36u3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one line of jQuery:

`$("#box").scrollLeft(480);`

Comment: But what happend if his page have just need jQuery for that ?

Answer (score -1):

**Use direction rtl**

```
overflow: auto; 
direction:rtl;
```