# How to make only the horizontal scroll bar to scroll from Right to Left Direction but not the Vertical Scroll bar of same div

Tags: jquery, python-2.7

I want the horizontal scroll bar to move from right to Left direction but the vertical scroll bar of same div should be in left position and work as it is(top to bottom)

Refrenced below link:
[Scroll horizontally starting from right to left with CSS overflow:scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293456/scroll-horizontally-starting-from-right-to-left-with-css-overflowscroll)

```
I tried the below code:
   #scrollid{
      direction: rtl;
    }
```

Expected only horizontal Scroll bar to move from right to left
But the vertical bar position also moved to opposite direction(from right to left)

Like below:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.Please help with the solution.